# 404 page when refreshing Angular SPA on Digital Ocean App Platform

Tags: angular, single-page-application, digital-ocean, static-site

I have been testing out an Angular single page app on the new Digital Ocean App Platform as a Static Site.

The Angular app loads fine when I access the root URL and navigate to different pages by clicking links. However, when I refresh the browser on any of the pages, I get a 404 error.

Does the Digital Ocean App Platform need an nginx.conf file? Am I missing a step where I need to enable pushstate in the environment?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you getting 404 on any page refresh or just root page refresh ?

Comment: I’m getting a 404 on the refresh of any page.

Comment: Are you deploying your app behind nginx? if so you need to configure nginx to make it work properly when 404 error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE (Nov 24, 2020) The control panel now supports the Catchall Document option in the component settings under the “Custom Pages” section.

per https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/angular-routes-not-working-on-static-app

Comment: Could you describe how to use it in your answer?

Comment: @Machado from memory, you just need to set up a catch all document in your Digital ocean settings.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**

You can now officially use `catchall_document` property instead of `error_document` in this instructions.

---

I think official SPAs in app platform are not possible right now. More informations here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/digital-ocean-apps-spa-application

But there is a workaround for now.

Create `app.yaml` file

```html
name: APP_NAME
region: fra
static_sites:
- build_command: |-
    git init
    git clean  -d  -f .
    git remote add origin https://github.com/REPOSITORY
    git fetch origin $BRANCH_NAME
    git checkout $COMMIT_SHA
    npm install
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    ng build --prod
  environment_slug: node-js
  github:
    branch: master
    deploy_on_push: true
    repo: REPOSITORY
  name: APP_NAME
  error_document: index.html
  routes:
  - path: /
```

In this file we set `error_document` to `index.html` (our index file). Every page is now redirected to index file.

Then you have to run doctl command to create new app using `app.yaml` file. You have to use this command in order to apply this configuration file.

```
doctl apps create --spec app.yaml
```

After that go to your app platform dashboard and you can see your SPA application

How to setup `doctl`? https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/apis-clis/doctl/how-to/install/

How to view my current `.yaml` settings? In app dashboard click on **settings** tab and in **App spec** row click on **view**

That's it

Comment: I just talked to people on DigitalOcean and they recently added a new option to static sites: catchall_document. So we can change the "error_document: index.html" to "catchall_document: index.html". I tested it here and it worked perfectly! =]

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to use "#" before angular routes, like this: "myapp.com/#/someroute" (https://angular.io/guide/router).

In app-routing.module.ts set the parameter "useHash" to true on RouterModule.forRoot:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: true,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

I'm having the same issue here and it worked just fine.
I'll use this way until DigitalOcean solve this behaviour.